# how to get ordered nested promises Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have multiple nested asyn  calls but when I execute my script order of call are not respected.

My Angular code

```
saveArticles(articles, action) {
    articles.forEach(element => {
      let blobs = [];
      if (element['files'] ) {
        let files: any[] = JSON.parse(element['files']);
        for (let k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
         //async service 
          this.filesService
            .getBinaryURI(files[k].url)
            .then(blob => {
              let blobElement = {
                fileName: files[k].name,
                fileType: files[k].type,
                blob: blob,
              };
              blobs.push(blobElement);
            })
            .finally(() => {
              if (k == files.length - 1 ) {
                //async service 
                this.articleService.createArticle(element, this.artId, blobs);
              }
            });
        }
      } 
    });
  }
//...
saveArticles(articles, "edit");
saveArticles(articles, "create");
```

Please someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous *callbacks* generally have no defined ordering (naturally, some do such as `setTimeout` - STFM); the original calls themselves are ordered within their own execution context. While the ordering of each callback can be guaranteed using *individual promise chaining*, including that implicit in [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), it is often better to write the callbacks such that the order does not matter – and to otherwise group asynchronous operation in logical groups.

Writing the callbacks such that the order does not matter allows *asynchronous operations* to run *in parallel*, as any form of chaining adds a sequence serialization step. This can also be achieved with higher constructs like “wait all”; again, where the ordering of each wait (callback) is independent.

For example, in the case above, instead of using `k == files.length - 1`, keep a simple counter (initially set to the length of the files ) and decrement it. Then the last callback is the last, regardless of k. Next, insert into `blobs[k]` instead of pushing, so that each blob is in order with respect to the loop ordering.

When using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), the finally would be handling the success of that new promise, given the result of all now-resolved input promises, and each input promise handler would return the blob (instead of pushing to an array). Avoiding the side-effect to blobs is critical in this case, as is using the loop index as presented above.

---

For example, assuming there is no relation required the two calls to `saveArticles`, the code can be restructured such that the order of the callbacks is not relevant. This is done by making the ordering 'stable', regardless of any deviations in callback order.

```
let files: any[] = JSON.parse(element['files']);
let blobs = new Array(files.length);
let remaining = files.length;

for (let k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
  this.filesService
    .getBinaryURI(files[k].url)
    .then(blob => {
      let blobElement = {
        fileName: files[k].name,
        fileType: files[k].type,
        blob: blob,
      };
      // Order of blobs is preserved, in relationship to the request
      // ordering, regardless of when the callback is invoked.
      blobs[k] = blobElement;
    })
    .finally(() => {
      // The last promise, regardless of "k" ordering, triggers the
      // next action; if a promise failed, a blob indices may be null.
      remaining -= 1;
      if (remaining == 0) {
        this.articleService.createArticle(element, this.artId, blobs);
      }
    });
}
```

While this change is to illustrate a point, there is no relationship between the ordering of requests between each `saveArticles`, or a way to wait on the completion of the entire operation. Keep reading..

---

As an improved alternative, consider using Promise *return values* and *chaining*. This affords more flexibility and reduce code complexity and intricacies through a higher-level operation. This approach also allows further aggregation and ordering between the `saveArticle` calls, without artificially forcing each request to wait on the previous request.

```
let files: any[] = JSON.parse(element['files']);
let reqs = [];

for (let k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
  var reqPromise = this.filesService
    .getBinaryURI(files[k].url)
    .then(blob => {
      let blobElement = {
        fileName: files[k].name,
        fileType: files[k].type,
        blob: blob,
      };
      // Return value - NO SIDE EFFECTS
      return blobElement;
    });

  // Store each promise in an array, although a sequence could also be
  // generated with 'map' or similar.. the individual XHR requests may be
  // running or queued or finished. However, none of the callbacks are
  // invoked yet. Such is a note, although it doesn't matter much,
  // as promises and chaining defers reactions.
  reqs.push(reqPromise);
}

// All the asynchronous operations can run in parallel, subject to
// other limits such as number of concurrent XHR request.
// A "wait all" promise will only (successfully) resolve when all
// input asynchronous operations are complete and promises are resolved.

let onAll = Promise.all(reqs).then((blobs) => {
  // blobs is an array representing the return values of the
  // input promises, in the original input promise order.
  // Returning the new promise here adds it to the chain too!
  return this.articleService.createArticle(element, this.artId, blobs);
});
```

The advantage of the second way, which might not be immediately obvious, is the `saveArticles` calls themselves can return the 'all promise'. This allows further composition and ordering control, including the ability to correctly wait for the completion.

```
// Promise.all returns a promise, which can be returned from the method
return onAll;

// And then this can used in the caller (eg. if marked async);
// or could use [await] Promise.all here if only the overall sequence matters.
// Another nicety of await is that it will throw on rejections.
await saveArticles(articles, "edit");   // save ALL these, waiting for completion
await saveArticles(articles, "create"); // THEN save all these, waiting for completion
```